# Native VLAN on Trunk port of Zyxel GS1910

Tags: cisco, switch, vlan, trunk

If I have a configuration on a Cisco switch;

```
   int Gi 0/48
    switchport mode trunk
    switchport trunk native vlan 100
    switchport trunk allowed vlan 101-110
```

Configuration on a Zyxel Switch is abit more complicated as the port has to be a member of the vlans it will Tag and untag. but the PVID is set to only one VLAN ID. Tx_tag is set to Untag_PVID on the trunk port facing the cisco switch.

However this does not work,
My question is in Zyxel is the PVID the native vlan of the switch port?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 5):

Depending on the model - it may not support both tagged and untagged traffic on the same switchport. The GS1910 is one such model.

Either tag all or tag none.

Just got off the phone with Tech Support to be told what I had already figured out...
Good Luck